# Free tool/framework/program to create high quality rest API documentation?

Tags: gratis, rest, documentation

Could you please recommend free tool/framework/program to create high quality rest API documentation?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The best place to document your API is generally within the code that implements that API - it is the place where the documentation is most likely to stay in step with the implementation. This is normally done with some specifically formatted comments.

There are a number of tools which can extract the documentation from the code (depending on  the implementation language) but my personal favourites are:

1. [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) - This is a python based toolchain with "[domains](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html)" & extensions for several other programming languages which can combine ReStructuredText *and MarkDown* files with information extracted from the API source code to produce excellent documentation in a number of output formats. It is compatible with ReadTheDocs and GitHub for automatically (re-)generating your documentation. Specifically there is a command line [api-doctool](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html) *and the [javasphinx](https://bronto.github.io/javasphinx/) extension provides a [javasphix-apidoc](https://bronto.github.io/javasphinx/#javasphinx-apidoc) equivelent for java.*
2. [DoxyGen](https://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) - the classic tool for generating documentation from your source code.

**Both** tools are:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Multi-platform *(Doxygen is OS/X, Linux & Windows while Sphinx will run anywhere python will).*
- Can generate multiple output formats including HTML, man pages, plain text and LaTeX *for pdf generation.* plus others.
- Can be included in your build process to automatically regenerate the documentation on each or specific builds.
- Can produce structured, cross linked, searchable documentation including diagrams, etc.
- Provide mechanisms for customising the look of the output - [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html) via custom html, css & xml files & Sphinx via [Templates](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/templating.html) & Custom Builders.
- Produce good looking documentation however by default Sphinx produces more modern looking documentation.

Comment: Hi Steve. Unrelated, if you have the time, could you take a look at this please? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120033/lizard-in-a-st0rm